# How do I compute total of values in UITableView cells?

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UITableView`. I have a list of "expenses" that gets saved to `CoreData`. This is as usual. `NSFetchedResultsController` handles everything as it should.

Every `Expense` entity has a .amount value (Double).

At the top of a tableview there's a label that shows the `totalDebt`. totalDebt is just every expense .amount added together (could be positive, negative, or zero).

The app lets you add or delete an item (so a cell, so an entity).

How should I compute the value for the `totalDebtLabel`?

I tried putting a `refreshTotalDebtLabel()` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but every time the table reloads every cell is computed, even cells that were already computed.
I tried other solutions but they all seem to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to create a `refreshLabel` method to be called whenever the data changes. You can catch that in various ways, e.g. in the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods, or when a text field or editing controller returns.

In the refresh method, leverage key-value-coding (KVC) to make it really simple.

```
let sum = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount") as! Double
// populate the label with the sum
```

If you are using primitives (such as `Double`) in your managed object subclass, you might have to refactor with `NSNumber` which is guaranteed to work and will also reliably hold your `Double` values. (In this case use ...`as! NSNumber`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this inside the table methods. You will have to calculate the `totalDebt` outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For example, just after you fetch the array of expenses, you can use a loop to calculate the `totalDebt` and set it in the label.

```
func refreshTotalDebtLabel()
{
    let expenses = NSArray() //fetched from core data
    let totalDebt : CGFloat = 0

    expenses.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (expenseObj, index, stop) -> Void in
        totalDebt += expenseObj.amount
    }

    print("Total Debt = %f", totalDebt)

    self.totalDebtLabel.text = String("$ %0.2f", totalDebt)
}
```